# move all files in a folder to another?

Tags: php, file

when moving one file from one location to another i use

```
rename('path/filename', 'newpath/filename');
```

how do you move all files in a folder to another folder? tried this one without result:

```
rename('path/*', 'newpath/*');
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the original directory?

Comment: it would be good to keep the original folder...not this time but maybe another time i will have to keep it..i can suspect what your approach is=)

Comment: but i noticed that ive got files in destination folder that i want to keep. and then your approach doesnt work cause it doesnt allow to move the folder to a destination folder that already contains files

Comment: seems very difficult to do such a trivial thing in php..weird:/

Comment: I've updated my solution below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another/2082164#2082164

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A slightly verbose solution:

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");
// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";
// Cycle through all source files
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: i have files in the destination folder and i want to keep them. just move the files from a temporary folder to that folder so you ADD files all the time.

Comment: i dont get the line: if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue; what is it doing?

Comment: Noname, two of the items in this array will be "." representing "current" directory, and ".." representing "previous" directory. When we come across these, we just "continue," meaning we skip the current iteration.

Comment: it was a great function that worked except if there were directories in the source folder. is there a way to circumvent this? and arent there libraries with classes for these operations? zend framework?

Comment: This is a decent solution, however the better way to do this is with PHP's rename() function as shown in the answers below.  Less code = faster process speed. :)

Comment: There is a typo in your code ... last line should be unlink($delete)

Answer (score 19):

Please try this solution, it's tested successfully ::

> ```
> <?php
>   $files = scandir("f1");
>   $oldfolder = "f1/";
>   $newfolder = "f2/";
>   foreach($files as $fname) {
>       if($fname != '.' && $fname != '..') {
>           rename($oldfolder.$fname, $newfolder.$fname);
>       }
>   }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Simple, short and works!

Answer (score 16):

An alternate using rename() and with some error checking:

```
$srcDir = 'dir1';
$destDir = 'dir2';

if (file_exists($destDir)) {
  if (is_dir($destDir)) {
    if (is_writable($destDir)) {
      if ($handle = opendir($srcDir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
          if (is_file($srcDir . '/' . $file)) {
            rename($srcDir . '/' . $file, $destDir . '/' . $file);
          }
        }
        closedir($handle);
      } else {
        echo "$srcDir could not be opened.\n";
      }
    } else {
      echo "$destDir is not writable!\n";
    }
  } else {
    echo "$destDir is not a directory!\n";
  }
} else {
  echo "$destDir does not exist\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

tried this one?:

```
     <?php

     $oldfolderpath = "old/folder";
     $newfolderpath = "new/folder";

     rename($oldfolderpath,$newfolderpath);
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I tried to use the `rename()` function as described and I kept getting the error back that there was `no such file or directory`.  I placed the code within an if else statement in order to ensure that I really did have the directories created.  It looked like this:

```
$tempDir = '/home/site/images/tmp/';
$permanentDir = '/home/site/images/' . $claimid; // this was stored above
mkdir($permanentDir,0775);
if(is_dir($permanentDir)){
    echo $permanentDir . ' is a directory';
    if(is_dir($tempDir)){
        echo $tempDir . ' is a directory';
    }else{
        echo $tempDir . ' is not a directory';
    }
}else{
    echo $permanentDir . ' is not a directory';
}

rename($tempDir . "*", $permanentDir);
```

So when I ran the code again, it spit out that both paths were directories.  I was stumped.  I talked with a coworker and he suggested, "Why not just rename the temp directory to the new directory, since you want to move all the files anyway?"

Turns out, this is what I ended up doing.  I gave up trying to use the wildcard with the `rename()` function and instead just use the `rename()` to rename the temp directory to the permanent one.

so it looks like this.

```
$tempDir = '/home/site/images/tmp/';
$permanentDir = '/home/site/images/' . $claimid; // this was stored above
mkdir($permanentDir,0775);

rename($tempDir, $permanentDir);
```

This worked beautifully for my purposes since I don't need the old tmp directory to remain there after the files have been uploaded and "moved".

Hope this helps.  If anyone knows why the wildcard doesn't work in the `rename()` function and why I was getting the error stating above, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Move or copy the way I use it

```
function copyfiles($source_folder, $target_folder, $move=false) {
    $source_folder=trim($source_folder, '/').'/';
    $target_folder=trim($target_folder, '/').'/';
    $files = scandir($source_folder);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            if ($move) {
                rename($source_folder.$file, $target_folder.$file);
            } else {
                copy($source_folder.$file, $target_folder.$file);
            }
        }
    }   
}

function movefiles($source_folder, $target_folder) {
    copyfiles($source_folder, $target_folder, $move=true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
rename('path/*', 'newpath/');

I do not see a point in having an asterisk in the destination

Answer (score 0):

If the target directory doesn't exist, you'll need to create it first:

```
mkdir('newpath');
rename('path/*', 'newpath/');
```

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. It would be great if the rename function supported globs, but as of PHP7, that does not appear to be the case. Example: `rename(/home/eric/wordpress/files/.tmp-checksum/*,/home/eric/wordpress/files/core): No such file or directory`
However, running `ls /home/eric/wordpress/files/.tmp-checksum/*` in a bash shell does show many files.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note; when you copy files to another folder, their last changed time becomes current timestamp. So you should [touch()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) the new files.

```
... (some codes for directory looping) ...
if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
   $delete[] = $source.$file;

   $filetimestamp = filemtime($source.$file); 
   touch($destination.$file,$filetimestamp);
}
... (some codes) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone or not, but thought I'd post anyway. Had a challenge where I has heaps of movies I'd purchased and downloaded through various online stores all stored in one folder, but all in their own subfolders and all with different naming conventions. I wanted to move all of them into the parent folder and rename them all to look pretty. all of the subfolders I'd managed to rename with a bulk renaming tool and conditional name formatting. the subfolders had other files in them i didn't want. so i wrote the following php script to, 1. rename/move all files with extension mp4 to their parent directory while giving them the same name as their containing folder, 2. delete contents of subfolders and look for directories inside them to empty and then rmdir, 3. rmdir the subfolders.

```
$handle = opendir("D:/Movies/");
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && is_dir($file)) {
    $newhandle = opendir("D:/Movies/".$file);
    while($newfile = readdir($newhandle)) {
        if ($newfile != "." && $newfile != ".." && is_file("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile)) {
            $parts = explode(".",$newfile);
            if (end($parts) == "mp4") {
                if (!file_exists("D:/Movies/".$file.".mp4")) {
                    rename("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile,"D:/Movies/".$file.".mp4");
                }
                else {
                    unlink("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile);
                }
            }
            else { unlink("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile); }
        }
        else if ($newfile != "." && $newfile != ".." && is_dir("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile)) {
            $dirhandle = opendir("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile);
            while ($dirfile = readdir($dirhandle)){
                if ($dirfile != "." && $dirfile != ".."){
                    unlink("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile."/".$dirfile);
                }
            }
            rmdir("D:/Movies/".$file."/".$newfile);
        }
    }
    unlink("D:/Movies/".$file);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i move all my .json files from root folder to json folder with this

```
foreach (glob("*.json") as $filename) {
    rename($filename,"json/".$filename);
}
```

pd: someone 2020?

Comment: Is this question or answer ?