# Addin an edge for this loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to move some files from a directory to another directory , I found this script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another) but this script loops through all the files, what I want is to change this script to loop through only 50 files. the code:

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");
// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";
// Cycle through all source files
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop, not a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Nicholas Yes I tried but it didn't work: *for ($i=1; $i < 500; $i++) {
      if (in_array($files, array(".",".."))) continue;
      // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
      if (copy($source.$files, $destination.$files)) {
        $delete[] = $source.$files;
      }
    }*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop, not a foreach loop.

A `for` loop is more sensible in this case because you're looping a definite number of times, each time this code is run.

`foreach` loops are used to iterate through an entire array or object.

It's a sense of purpose. When another programmer looks at your code they'll know immediately that you're looping 50 times, not looping an entire array.

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("source");

// Identify directories
$source = "source/";
$destination = "destination/";

for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
    $file = $files[$i];

    if( !$file ) 
        break;

    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
    if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
       $delete[] = $source.$file;
    }
}

// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Comment: He only wants to loop through the first 50, `foreach` is usually used when you want to loop through everything in an array. It's a sense of purpose. Using a `foreach` and a `break` is a little silly when a normal `for` loop is available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get it clearly, but have you considered a simple count?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
 if($i < 50) {
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    unlink($source.$file); //move unlink here to avoid a second loop
  }
  else{
   break;
  }
 }
 $i++;
}
```

Comment: That still loops through all of the files even though we're done at 50. Edit: Ah, you've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `count` and stop the loop when it reach 50 times:

```
$count = 0;
$maxiterations = 50;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($count  < $maxiterations) {
        if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
        // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
        if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
            $delete[] = $source.$file;
        }
        $i++;
    } 
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```