# extract the contents of a folder

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I have been reading [extractto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php) for the php manual, and I understand exactly what it does. but my zip had:

```
name.zip
--foler
----files
```

I want the files, I don't want the folder, I just want the files. These **will** over write files in a path I am extracting too - which is **fine**. The problem is, how do I go inside a directory (with a specific name) inside a zip and extract that directories contents?

My end result will look like:

`place/to/extract/files`

**not!**

`place/to/extract/folder/files`

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to move all the content in the parent directory AFTER unzipping, or use tarbombs...

Comment: Yes, this is probably the simplest way of solving this problem. Keep doing what you are doing right now and then move the files to the parent directory.

You may want to look at this question to learn how to move your files from one directory to another. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another