# Move uploaded file function in php is not working

Tags: php

Following is my piece of code which moves file to particular directory.

```
foreach($files as $dir_file)    //Getting Path of XML file
        {
            echo "\nDir Files: ".$dir_file."\n";

            if($dir_file != "." && $dir_file != "..")
            {
                if(strpos($dir_file,'.xml'))     
                {
                    echo "\nXML file found\n";
                    $xmlPath=$path."/".$dir_file;
                    // return ReadXML($xmlPath);
                }
                if(strpos($dir_file,'.JPG'))
                {
                    echo "\n FOund \n";
                    $ret=move_uploaded_file($dir_file, 'upload/'.$dir_file));
                     echo "\n retunr values: ".$ret;
                }  
            }
```

I have checked all permission and it is 777. but move upload file function is not moving my file to particular directory. it is also not returning anything. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show what $files look like?

Comment: First, turn on error reporting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php  If you still can't identify the problem from the error message, then post the error message here.

Comment: Are these always files that have just been uploaded (i.e. in this same script)? If they're just files on the file system you might be wanting to `rename(...)` instead of `move_uploaded_file(...)` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: they are just image files and i am running it through SSH terminal

Comment: Are tou trying to upload a file using  xml filepath?

Comment: sir i have files placed in a directory i want to move these files to other folders

Comment: If you are trying to move the files form one directory to another then you have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php and this might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another

Comment: So these files have not *just been uploaded via an HTTP request?!*

Comment: In that case, you need use copy function and once it is copied after that u need to unlink the file.

Comment: rename function cut the files and paste to desired location i dunt want it to cut the files i want to copy

Comment: Well then **use `copy`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are to move files from one directory to another, you should use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function.

This is the example code:

```
$source = "YOUR_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/";
$destination = "YOUR_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY/";

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, array(".","..")))
        continue;

    //If file is copied successfully then mark it for deletion
    if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
        $delete[] = $source.$file;
    }
}
//If you want to delete the copied files then include these lines
//Delete all successfully copied files
foreach($delete as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)
>
> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file ***(meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism).*** If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

(Emphasis mine.) You can use `move_uploaded_file` only to *move files which have been uploaded*, where "uploaded" means "PHP has received the file in the current request and the file is currently in the `$_FILES` super global". Any other file is not movable by `move_uploaded_file`. This is exactly on purpose, `move_uploaded_file` is supposed to protect you from yourself and make sure you're only moving files uploaded by the user.

If you want to move any other file which has not *just been uploaded via HTTP POST*, use `copy` or `rename`.