# upload file from one folder to another php

Tags: php

```
    $path = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/Uploads/'; // Upload directory 
   // Decode content array.
    $ContentArray = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['content'] ) );
    foreach( $ContentArray as $ContentIndividualFilename )
    {
        echo $path.$ContentIndividualFilename;

        // Move uploaded files. 
        if( copy( $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$ContentIndividualFilename], $path.$ContentIndividualFilename) )
        {
        }
    }
```

this is wrong `$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$ContentIndividualFilename]` because i get here through ajax function without page refresh. `$ContentIndividualFilename` contains filenames of the files.How do i transfer the file to the required folder?

Comment: [upload file from one folder to another - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another)