# PHP moving all files in directory

Tags: php, file, rename, glob

I'm trying to move all files to another directory, but I can't get it to work.

```
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/*.csv"); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file) {
    if(is_file($file))
        rename($file, "archive/".basename($file));
    }
}
```

I got no errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get error message ?

Comment: Have you taken a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082138/move-all-files-in-a-folder-to-another ?

Comment: Try `glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/*.csv")` in case your DOCUMENT_ROOT does not end with a slash...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work. I did it without the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

```
$files = glob("files/*.csv"); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
    if(is_file($file)) {
        rename($file, "files/archive/" . basename($file)); // move file
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to debug your code ....

```
// here you missed the backslash, like it is mentioned by bufh
$files = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/*.csv"); 

var_dump($files); // to see if files with path were effectively returned by glob()

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(is_file($file))
        // i advice you to use Log4PHP ... it let you debug easily your code in development and production system (simple switch to debug mode...)
        // $log->debug(sprintf("this file:%s will be moved")); 
        rename($file, "archive/".basename($file));
    }
}
```